# Rails Prawnto PDFs fail to download in Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn, prawnto

I have a working Prawnto implementation, except for in IE versions 6 - 8. Here's my print method:

```
prawnto :inline => false, :filename => @purchase.deal.name + "-" + @purchase.customer.name+".pdf", :prawn => {:skip_page_creation=>true}
```

This works fine on Safari, FF and Chrome. You know, the sane browsers.

But on IE, the browser attempts to download the id number of the record; the URL looks like this:

https://domain.com/customers/print/24?format=pdf

It says "cannot download file '24'".

Any idea what I should be doing here?

Thanks,
Aaron.

Comment: As I continue to investigate, I've dug up other projects where I'm using the same code and having no problems with IE. The only difference I can see now between these projects is that this one runs on an SSL cert. Can that make a difference?

Comment: I've found another post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574108/rails-pdf-generation-with-prawn-in-ie7

Comment: Yup, seems like a permanent, known bug involving IE and SSL. Others have talked about hacking the headers, but I ended up doing this: http://chelsearobb.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/saving-a-prawn-pdf-to-file/

Answer (score 2):

I updated my answer over here:

[Rails PDF Generation with Prawn in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574108/rails-pdf-generation-with-prawn-in-ie7)

The middleware thing looked like it would work, but for whatever reason it didn't.  We set some headers on the controller action, and that seemed to work for us.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create pdf link without the SSL requirement until this gets sorted out.  If you're using the ssl_requirement plugin, use ssl_allowed instead of required and then generate the link without the https.

It's not what I would like to do, but it gets the job done for now.  I'm still looking into this as the other posted solution, to intercept the headers using Rack Middleware, didn't work for me.